# .NET - FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, authentication

I'm using FormsAuthentication in .NET

I would like to store some variables in the Session once a user has been logged in via FormsAuthentication

How would I do this? Is there a method/callback that occurs when a user is logged in?

Thanks

Comment: Describe more about what exactly you want to achieve using your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Authenticate` method for `FormsAuthentication` class is obsolete now. So to login you will need to use `Membership API`. Visit here to see how -

[MemebrShip API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Accessing form authentication data -

[FormsAuthentication Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx)

To know, how to save in session see this link -

[HttpContext.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using the Membership.ValidateUser to verify the user's authentication. This works fine and I can use context.Session to set a session variable upon logging in... however, if the user exits the browser, and re-visits the pages, the user is still logged in, and so I need those session variables to still persist. Any idea how to accomplish that?